# jquery load function after show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a function after a given DIV shows.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#next").click(function () {
          $("#nextwindow").show()
      });
  });


  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#pagetitle-up").click(function () {
          $.post('maindatabase.php', {
                  page: <? php echo $_GET[p]; ?> , sort: 1
              },
              function (data) {
                  var printthisline = "";
                  var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                  for (var i in data.results) {
                      printthisline += " <a href='main.php?p=" + data.results[i].id + "'> " + data.results[i].pagetitle + "</a>" + " | " + " <br> ";
                  }
                  document.getElementById("nexttable").innerHTML = printthisline;
              });
      });
  });
```

When trying to bind them together so that the function only runs once the initial DIV shows, it stops working. Any suggestions why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#next").click(function () {
        $("#nextwindow").show()
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nextwindow").on('show', function () {
        $.post('maindatabase.php', {
                page: <? php echo $_GET[p]; ?> , sort: 1
            },
            function (data) {
                var printthisline = "";
                var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                for (var i in data.results) {
                    printthisline += " <a href='main.php?p=" + data.results[i].id + "'> " + data.results[i].pagetitle + "</a>" + " | " + " <br> ";
                }
                document.getElementById("nexttable").innerHTML = printthisline;
            });
    });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: A little formatting goes a long way

Comment: There is no in-build onshow event, so try: `$("#nextwindow").show().trigger('show')` or handle it differently

Comment: you don't need to handle show, firstly it's not an event, secondly it's synchronous, so it's an unnecessary complication.

Comment: What I want is to run the function after a DIV is shown, so save bandwith with my MySQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger manually your custom `show` event:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Em5K/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#next").click(function () {
        $("#nextwindow").show().trigger('show');
    });
});
```

Or use callback:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Em5K/1/)

```
$("#nextwindow").show(0,myCallback);

function myCallback(){
      $.post(...);
}
```

That's said, why not call POST request on `#nextwindow` click???